# How open another viewController when i pushed on any row in UITableView?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

Help me please with my `tableView` in xCode.

So i have my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    UIView *containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, -150, 45)] autorelease];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 400, 40)] autorelease];

    headerLabel.text = @"My table";

    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];

    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [containerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = containerView;

    self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Eggs",@"Milk", @"Chocolate", @"Drink", @"Banana", @"Apple", @"Fruit", nil];        
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    //Поиск ячейки

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}



    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{

    UIViewController *Main = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Main animated:YES];

    UIViewController *Main2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main2"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Main2 animated:YES];

}
```

When i pushed on the row "Eggs" will open another viewController with eggs. But i want that, when i will push on the row "Milk" will open page with milk but when i pushed on the row @"milk" i have page with "Eggs"...Thanks for help...big thanks. I think it work with index..but i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it....

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        UIViewController *Main = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Main animated:YES];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {
        UIViewController *Main2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main2"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Main2 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you....